# How to set response header in nestjs with fastify

Tags: nestjs, fastify

I'm trying to set a custom reponse header in a nest js controller and using fastify.
Currently I'm trying to do:

```
@Post()
async methodName(@Res res){
res.set('key', 'value');
};
```

But I get the error: `res.set is not a function`
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was:

```
res.header('key', 'value');
```

Comment: What is the type for the `response`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are needing to set a static header value as well, you can always use the `@Header()` decorator on the route handler so you could have

```js
@Post()
@Header('key', 'value')
async method() {
  return something;
}
```

Comment: What if I want to pass a dynamic value to a header? Let's say a filename to the "Content-Disposition" header?

Comment: You could use `@Res({ passthrough: true }) response: FastifyReply` to do `response.header()` and still have Nest handle sending the response

Comment: ```@Res({ passthrough: true })``` did the trick for me.